# Query using COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, count, aggregate-functions

1st Table: **Employee**

```
+------------+-----------+----------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Age | Gender | Salary | JobID |
+------------+-----------+----------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
```

2nd Table: **JobTitle**

```
+-------+----------+----------------+--------+
| JobID | JobTitle | JobDescription | Status |
+-------+----------+----------------+--------+
```

Write one SQL query to count all employees and `GROUP BY` Age and Gender. (Output shows alias)

I've done the following queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) AS Number_Of_Employees
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Age, Gender;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total_Employees'
FROM Employee
WHERE Gender = 'M' OR Gender= 'F'
GROUP BY Age, Gender;
```

This is the result with both queries:

[image: This is the result with both queries]

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: I figured it out after I posted my question. It was to come up with one query to count all employees and GROUP BY Age and Gender.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer. I ended up running this query and I think it worked.

```
SELECT Age, Gender, 
COUNT(EmployeeID) AS Total_Employee
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Age, Gender;
```